# Rails: I18n producing odd results in placeholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, placeholder

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= form_tag searches_path, :method => 'get', :class => "nav_search" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "type", "publications" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, nil, :placeholder => t('publications') %>
<% end %>
```

And this in my en.yml file:

```
en:
  views:
    layout:
      publications: 'publications'
```

Although I18n works elsewhere on the site, whenever I put it in a placeholder like this, I get odd results. The text field contains this as a placeholder:

```
<span class=
```

Followed by this text outside of the placeholder:

```
Publications" type="text" />
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest thing here is to specify the full translation key like this :

```
<%= text_field_tag :query, nil, :placeholder => t('views.layout.publications') %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4.2, you can now just do:

`<%= f.text_field :query, placeholder: true %>`

and the i18n will pull the placeholder from:

`en.helpers.placeholder.model_name.query`